# Unable to find layout in included layout for Android app

Tags: android-layout, include

I have a layout file that reads as follows:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_below="@+id/gallery">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar_activity" >
    </include>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/create_profile_gallery" >
    </include>

    .
    .
    .
</RelativeLayout>
```

and it renders as follows:

[image]

The included layouts, tool_bar_activity and create_profile_gallery, respectively, are as follows:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle">

        .
        .
        .
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/categories_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

.
.
.
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

The problem I'm seeing is that findViewById returns null for categories_layout but not null for toolbar, even though both are contained in their respective (included) layouts:

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Get a pointer to the gallery layout. This is where gallery items will be inserted.
    categories_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.categories_layout);
```

Why should one layout be found but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

categories_layout can't be null since all views in the parent layout would be loaded into memory when onCreate method is called in case of an Activity.

Comment: That's what I thought, too.

Answer (score 0):

I had to inflate the view before being able to access its child elements:

```
                            // First, inflate the view that contains the layout we want to insert into.
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        // Get a pointer to the gallery layout. This is where gallery items will be inserted.
                        categories_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.categories_layout);
                        categories_layout.removeAllViews();
                        for (int i = 0; i < catNameObj.length; i++) {
                            // Get the view for the gallery items. These will be inserted into categories_layout after the all_categories list
                            // has been downloaded from the server, in downloadFile().
                            galleryView = vi.inflate(R.layout.category_list, null);

                            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) galleryView.findViewById(R.id.node);
                          .
                          .
                          .
```

etc.